# Laravel 4, view composer with parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Suppose I have this:

```
//controllers/BlogController.php
$data["post"] = $post = Blog::recent_post();
$data["posts_related"] = Blog::posts_related($post->category_id,5);
return View::make('blog.home', $data);

//views/sidebars/related.blade.php
@foreach($posts_related as $r)
<p>{{ $r->name }}</p>
@endforeach

//views/blog/home.blade.php
@include('sidebars.related')
```

My question is, how could I transfer:

```
$data["posts_related"] = Blog::posts_related($post->category_id,5);
```

To a view composer, since it seems I can't pass parameters to a view composer, but I can't be sure.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Composers are there to pass data to views, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, could you help me with an alternative? I was trying to replicate render partials from Rails 4. The best I could so far is `@include('sidebars.related', ['posts_related' => Blog::posts_related($post->category_id,5)]))` from within the view.

Comment: `@include` injects all variables available to the parent view into the nested view. So if you bind `$posts_related` to your `home` view, then in that view call `@include('sidebars.related')` then `$posts_related` is automatically given to that view as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In View Composer you can retrive data that passed to View.

```
View::composer('sidebars.related', function($view)
{
   //$data contains category_id
   $viewdata= $view->getData();

   //Retrive based on category_id
   $posts_related = Blog::posts_related($viewdata['category_id'],5);

   //pass related post to view
   $view->with('posts_related', $posts_related);
});
```

now everywhere you can use:

```
 View::make('sidebars.related')->with(array('category_id' => 6));
```